# How can I attach api-gateway's LambdaRestApi to CloudFrontWebDistribution?

Tags: aws-cdk

I have some problem in using aws-cdk.

I want to attach LambdaRestApi to CloudFrontWebDistribution.

It is easy to attach s3 bucket to CloudFrontWebDistribution, because there is some example in aws-cdk-examples.

But, I couldn't find some example for LambdaRestApi.

Can you give some reference for this?

Comment: It looks like it may not be supported yet. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1474